# Thrift Async HTTP Client in Java?

Tags: java, scala, thrift

I have a Thrift API Server in PHP which looks very much like this 
https://github.com/edvakf/Thrift-Example/blob/master/api.php

I'm writing a client in Scala using the official Apache Thrift library. 
https://github.com/apache/thrift

```
val clientFactory = new ArithmeticService.Client.Factory
val transport = new THttpClient(url)
val protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport)
val client = factory.getClient(protocol)
transport.open()
// do things with the client
transport.close()
```

My question is; how can one make it async (non-blocking)?

Comment: The same way you would in Java. Of course this means using the Java Future interfaces, which aren't as nice or idiomatic as the Scala ones. You might want to consider using Scrooge to generate a more idiomatic (Finagle-based) async client.

Comment: It turned out that TAsyncClient only supports TFramedTransport over TCP socket. So the answer to my question is it's not possible.

Comment: Instead, though, I found that there are sendXXX and recvXXX methods associated with every service method named XXX. Using an asynchronous HTTP client (such as ning AsyncHttpClient), I wrapped these methods.